# Imágenes en Python

Tags: python, spyder

Estoy estudiando tratamiento de imágenes con python. Tengo que separar la imagen a color en tres capas diferentes (rojo, azul y verde) y obtener tres imágenes para cada uno de los colores ya que tengo que aplicarlas unos filtros. No sé cómo separar las tres capas de colores.

He conseguido hacer lo siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

img_red=np.copy(img) # creo una copia de la imagen para preservar la original
img_red[:,:,1]=0
img_red[:,:,2]=0
plt.title("beach_ canal rojo")
plt.imshow(img_red)
```

Y efectivamente me devuelve la imagen en rojo. Pero no puedo utilizar librerías excepto la librería siguiente:

```
from PIL import Image
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo separar las capas y crear nuevas imágenes sin hacer uso de las librerías?

Comment: ¿De dónde se supone que obtienes `img`?¿Lo cargas usando `PIL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empecemos por cargar una imagen:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("Python.jpg")
```

Que sería la siguiente:

[image: Imagen]

Separarla en sus tres componentes es directo usando este objeto `img`:

```
r, g, b = img.split()
```

El problema es que si visualizas los componentes, los ves como mapas de gris:

[image: Roja]
[image: verde]
[image: Azul]

La visualización es de todas formas correcta, ya que una vez has separado los canales, cada canal no es más que una colección de pixeles en los que los valores van de 0 (negro) a 255 (máximo brillo del canal), que se visualizarían como blanco en las vistas anteriores.

Si no obstante lo que quieres es verlas en color, podemos usar el siguiente truco. Primero creo una imagen idéntica a cualquiera de esos tres canales, pero enteramente negra:

```
nula = r.point(lambda x: 0)
```

(Simplemente se está aplicando la transformación `lambda` a cada punto de la imagen, y esa transformación retorna cero).

Ahora puedes crear por separado tres imágenes respectivamente roja, verde y azul, cada una de ellas usando el canal `r`, `g` o `b` antes extraido, y poniendo la imagen nula en cada uno de los otros dos canales:

```
roja = Image.merge("RGB", (r, nula, nula))
verde = Image.merge("RGB", (nula, g, nula))
azul = Image.merge("RGB", (nula, nula, b))
```

Obteniendo así:

[image: roja]
[image: verde]
[image: azul]

Comment: Muchas gracias!! No es tan complicado cuando te lo explican! Me surge una duda, si yo aplico un filtro a cada una de estas imágenes y después quiero crear una nueva imagen tipo 'RGB' a partir de las tres imágenes con filtro, se podría hacer? Alguien podría darme alguna pista de como hacerlo?

Comment: Sí, claro. Para eso partirías de los canales `r`, `g`, y `b` "en blanco y negro". Aplicarías el filtro a cada uno de esos tres canales y al final harías `resultado = Image.merge("RGB", (r,g,b))` (siendo `r`, `g` y `b` los ya procesados). El truco de pasarlos a color es solo para verlos en color, pero internamente son solo niveles monocromos y esos son los que debes procesar separadamente.

Comment: Valee, perfecto! Creo que he entendido todo, muchas gracias por ayudarme!!